# Scrape Prometheus metrics from two endpoints in the same Kubernetes pod

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, prometheus

Using this sample prometheus config:

```
- job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
  tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: pod
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
    action: keep
    regex: true
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
    action: replace
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    regex: (.+)
  - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
    action: replace
    regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
    replacement: $1:$2
    target_label: __address__
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_namespace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
```

I have a pod that exposes two metric paths. One here /metrics/prometheus and another /metrics/executors/prometheus on the same port.

How can I use this sample config to use service discovery and scrape both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use annotations on Services rather than Pods. This way you could create two services, pointing to that same pod, while setting distinct annotations setting your scrape path.

Switching this one:

```
- source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
  action: replace
  target_label: __metrics_path__
  regex: (.+)
```

For that one:

```
- source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
  action: replace
  target_label: __metrics_path__
  regex: (.+)
```

Then, move your prometheus.io/path annotation from Pods to Services.